# How to map columns and data from from a source xls file to a destination xls file

Tags: python

Im new to learning python and as a starting step, wanted some help in coding.
Im trying to map a source xls file with a destination xls file. Header of column1 in source is the header of column2 in destination file. I want to map the same data of column 1 in source to column2 of destination. I have attached source and dest files for reference. 
In the pic, item code of source is in the first column , but item code in destination is in the 2nd column. I want to make sure data of item code in source is populated in item code(column2) in destination. Any help is appreciated[enter image description here][1]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please be specific and provide a **[mcve]** example. In particular, you are encouraged to share your existing code and tell us where it is not working as expected. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options to start with:

a. Export it to CSV and use the builtin CSV module to read and write the files.

b. Or install and use the Openpyxl module to access the xls files directly.

Whichever route you go, put together some code, then if you have questions, show the code you've done and ask a specific question.